# Overload function template based on parameter function argument type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm a class that looks like this:

```
template<typename A>
struct List {
    ...
    template<typename Fn, typename B = typename std::result_of<Fn(A)>::type>
    List<B> map(Fn f) const
    { ... }
};
```

I'm trying to overload `map` and allow it to accept a getter of type `A` as argument, so that we can do `foos.map(&Foo::bar)`, where `bar` is a getter of class `Foo`. The following function works:

```
template<typename Fn, typename B = typename std::result_of<Fn(A*)>::type>
List<B> mapGet(Fn getter) const
{ ... }
```

But if I try to use the same name `map`, the compiler complains it's ambiguous. My question is, when `Fn` is a getter wouldn't the former `std::result_of` fail, effectively disabling one of the overloaded `map`s? Also, is there any way to make overloading possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, when `Fn` is a getter wouldn't the former `std::result_of` fail, effectively disabling one of the overloaded maps?

I'm guessing by "getter" what you really mean is pointer to member function? In which case, `std::result_of` works just fine with those. Let's say we have some type `Foo`:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int i) : i(i) { }
    int bar() const { return i; }
    int i;
};
```

You can use pointers to members as you'd expect:

```
using T = std::result_of_t<decltype(&Foo::bar)(Foo )>;
static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>{}, "!");
```

The only difference is how you actually call `f`. For C++17, there's [`std::invoke()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) which will work with all the invokable types, otherwise you could just directly use `std::bind()` or write your own wrapper which does the same thing.

As an example and ignoring copying, forwarding, and reserving, we could write `map` like:

```
template <class A, class F, class B = std::result_of_t<F(A)>>
std::vector<B> map(std::vector<A> xs, F f)
{
    auto binder = std::bind(f, std::placeholders::_1);

    std::vector<B> r;
    for (auto& x : xs) {
        r.push_back(binder(x));
    }
    return r;
}
```

That's works just as well for actual function objects:

```
std::vector<int> vs{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<double> ds = map(vs, [](int i){return i * 2.0; });
```

As it does for our `Foo` with a pointer to member:

```
std::vector<Foo> foos{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> is = map(foos, &Foo::bar);
```

Comment: Currently in `mapGet` I do `(x.*getter)()`, where `x` is an element of the list. I'm not sure if I get you; is it possible to overload `map`, then?

Comment: @ZizhengTai You don't need two overloads of `map` - the only difference is how you're calling `f` on each object. All the other logic is the same.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean!

Comment: @ZizhengTai Added an example for `map` illustrating what I mean.